# --use-file-for-fake-audio-capture doesn't play on google.com

Tags: selenium, google-chrome-devtools, webrtc

I am trying to make an audio file play on google.com. I have the following code:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.AddArguments(
        //"--allow-file-access-from-files",
        "--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream",
        //"--allow-file-access",
        "--use-file-for-fake-audio-capture=" + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/audio.wav",
        "--use-fake-device-for-media-stream"
            );
        IWebDriver chrome = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

this code opens a chrome window with the use of selenium in C# and everything works as expected. When i go to an online audio recorder or https://appr.tc/?debug=loopback then my audio file plays just like it is supposed to do. However, when i go to google.com and I click on the search by voice button at the end of the searchbar nothing happens. (when I just talk then google.com recognizes my voice) What am I missing and why doesn't it work? I am trying to recreate this but in C# http://www.testautomationguru.com/selenium-webdriver-google-voice-search-automation-using-arquillian-graphene/. Is there some kind of javascript code I could execute on the page to make it work? I wouldn't mind using a firefoxdriver instead of a chrome one if that solves the problem.

Thanks

Edit: I found a little more information on https://webrtc.org/testing/ so I suppose this means that google.com doesn't make use of the webrtc getUserMedia() call to get the audio? Any way I could modify the page so it does or can I change some other setting? I also just checked https://speechnotes.co/ and on that site my audio also isn't detected but my real microphone is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

google.com makes use of webKitSpeechRecognition() in javascript which is the built in chrome speech recognition, check[chrome speech recognition WebKitSpeechRecognition() not accepting input of fake audio device --use-file-for-fake-audio-capture or audio file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50774560/chrome-speech-recognition-webkitspeechrecognition-not-accepting-input-of-fake)

Answer (score 0):

This should now be fixed:

- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1472056
- https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/4779629

This change is live in https://www.google.com/chrome/beta/ (118.0.5993.11-1) as of typing this post. If anyone can confirm that the bug is fixed, please post here so others see it.

Comment: If you are not sure that the bug is fixed and solves the problem described in the question this should be a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: Please don't add the same answer to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227)  https://stackoverflow.com/a/77145163/7733418