# chrome speech recognition WebKitSpeechRecognition() not accepting input of fake audio device --use-file-for-fake-audio-capture or audio file

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, selenium-chromedriver, speech-to-text, device-driver, webkitspeechrecognition

I would like to use chrome speech recognition WebKitSpeechRecognition() with the input of an audio file for testing purposes. I could use a virtual microphone but this is really hacky and hard to implement with automation, but when I tested it everything worked fine and the speechrecognition converted my audio file to text. now I wanted to use the following chrome arguments:

```
--use-file-for-fake-audio-capture="C:/url/to/audio.wav"
--use-fake-device-for-media-stream
--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream
```

This worked fine on voice recorder sites for example and I could hear the audio file play when I replayed the recording. But for some reason when I try to use this on WebKitSpeechRecognition of chrome then it doesn't use the fake audio device but instead my actual microphone. Is there any way I can fix this or test my audio files on the website? I am using C# and I couldn't really find any useful info on automatically adding, managing and configuring virtual audio devices. What approaches could I take?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is now fixed.


- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1472056
- https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/4779629


With Chrome v119 you will be able to inject fake audio when WebKitSpeechRecognition is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it turns out this is not possible because chrome and google check if you are using a fake mic ect, they do this specifically to prevent this kind of behavior so people cannot get free speech to text. There is a paid api available from google (first 60 minutes per month are free)